# External Build Issues error configuring?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I wasn't having the Cmake option in my SDK, so I downloaded it from main source and pasted the Bin file as well as other files in the: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\SDK\cmake there was no problem whatsoever. But I am getting external build issues... And there are no files in cpp folder as well.

[image: Snapshot of my issue]